# three.js can an object be rotated and moved at the same time

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello and thanks for your time. I'm trying to move an object and rotate it at the same time. While preforming both actions the object moves erratically. I have read that rotation changes the axis in some way. Is that true? Here's the code. I have tried to rotate using both a world axis and a object axis but having the same issue.

```
   var rotObjectMatrix;
   function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians) {
      rotObjectMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      rotObjectMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);

      object.matrix.multiply(rotObjectMatrix);

      object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
  }


var rotWorldMatrix;
     // Rotate an object around an arbitrary axis in world space       
    function rotateAroundWorldAxis(object, axis, radians) {
       rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
       rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
       rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);               

       object.matrix = rotWorldMatrix;

       object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
  }

          function spriteAI2() {
            //var ranTen = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+2);
            var xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
            var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
            var zAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
            rotateAroundObjectAxis(meshSprite, zAxis, Math.PI / 180);
            if (meshSprite.position.x > 30 && meshSprite.position.x <= 450) { 
            meshSprite.translateX( -6 );
            } else if (meshSprite.position.y > 30 && meshSprite.position.y <= 250) {
            meshSprite.translateY( -6);
            } else if (meshSprite.position.z > 30 && meshSprite.position.z <= 350) {
            meshSprite.translateZ( -6 );
            } else if (meshSprite.position.x < -30 && meshSprite.position.x >= -450) {
            meshSprite.translateX( 6 );
            } else if (meshSprite.position.y < -30 && meshSprite.position.y >= -250) {
            meshSprite.translateY( 6 );
            } else if (meshSprite.position.z < -30 && meshSprite.position.z >= -350) {
            meshSprite.translateZ( 6 );
            } else if (meshSprite.position.x < 31 && meshSprite.position.y < 31 && meshSprite.position.z < 31 && meshSprite.position.x > -31 && meshSprite.position.y > -31 && meshSprite.position.z > -31) { 
            var locX = Math.floor((Math.random()*450)+1);
            locX *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            var locY = Math.floor((Math.random()*250)+1);
            locY *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            var locZ = Math.floor((Math.random()*350)+1);
            locZ *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
            scene.remove(meshSprite);
            //texture.dispose();
            c2ImgMaterial.dispose();
            meshSprite.position.set( locX, locY, locZ );
            scene.add( meshSprite );
            //c2Sprite.clone;
            }
        }
```

Comment: See the three.js examples and three.js source code. Start with `Object3D.js`. If you are having problems, learn how to set up a jsfiddle so others can see a live example. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hbt9c/61/

Answer (score 0):

I have located the source of my problem. It seems that in three.js objects can be moved either locally or globally. In my case I was using the local version.

```
            meshSprite.translateX(-6); // Local

            var delta = clock.getDelta(); // Global
            var moveDistance = 125 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
            meshSprite.position.x += moveDistance;
```

After switching to the global form of movement there is no conflict when rotating.
A more extensive explanation can be found at the following URL.
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mesh-Movement.html